# SharePoint List Search

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have a list with numerous Items.

I want to search for a term in the List and have the ability to select the Item in which the search term exists.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will probably want to create a "search scope" and use that to limit results to a particular url.